# Concurrency in Jmeter using throughput controller

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I have 3 different scenario's in Jmeter which i have in a thread group under 3 throughput controller.
Thread Group(4)
 -ThroughputController1 -50%
 -ThroughputController2 -25 %
 -ThroughputController3 -25 %
When I run the test, calls to the method are made sequentially for all the controllers,  Is there a way where i can run all the test scenario's concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

- For running thread groups concurrently untick `Run Thread Groups consecutively` box in your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
- Each JMeter thread executes samplers as they go upside down. If you want concurrency - add more threads and provide enough loops as if the thread doesn't have any more samplers to execute it's being shut down. If you want controlled concurrency - add a [Constant Throughput Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer) and specify desired number of requests per time unit.

Comment: I can add additional Thread groups for each individual scenarios as that will work fine and here i have to specify the number of threads in each thread Groups manually every time(lets imagine if i have created 15 different thread groups I have to edit all 15 thread group's No. of thread every time),but my goal is create a single thread group and specify the number of threads in a whole and I should specify the percentage of Threads in each scenarios by using a Throughput controller/Some controller so that i can change only the number of threads of one thread group at a time.